# Questions on C expression

Tags: c

Here is a program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    a=12;
    ++a;
    b=a++;
    c=++a;
    printf("a=%d,b=%d,c=%d",a,b,c);
    getch();
}
```

The answers are a=15,b=13, c=15. But how?

Answer (score 2):

- `x=++y` means `y` is incremented before `x` receives the value of `y`.
- `x=y++` means `y` is incremented after `x` receives the value of `y`.

In the code:

- The first `++a` makes `a = 13`.
- The line `b=a++` makes `b=a` (13) and after that `a = 14`.
- The line `c=++a` makes `a = 15` and after that `c = a` (15).

Answer (score 0):

The expression `a++` evaluates to the current value of `a`; as a side effect, `a` is incremented.  Thus, the expression

```
b = a++;
```

is equivalent to

```
b = a;
a = a + 1;
```

with the caveat that the exact timing of the updates to `a` and `b` with respect to each other isn’t specified.  IOW, it’s possible that the current value of `a` is stored in a register, then `a` is incremented, then the value in the register is written to `b`.  It’s possible that `a` and `b` are updated in parallel.  All that’s guaranteed is that `b` gets the previous value of `a`.

The expression `++a` evaluates to the current value of `a + 1`, and as a side effect increments `a`.  Thus, the expression

```
c = ++a;
```

is equivalent to

```
c = a + 1;
a = a + 1;
```

with the same caveat as above.

Answer (score 0):

++a means increment a, then use (in this case save).
a++ means use then increment

Answer (score 0):

++a or a++ both work as a=a+1 but  ++a first increases value of a by 1 and then assigns it to a. while a++ first assigns the value of a and then increments it by 1.

initially the value of a is declared as 12
statement '++a' first increases value of a by 1 and then assigns it to a. thus now, a=13

in statement b=a++, Value of a i.e. 13 is assigned to b and then it is incremented by 1. thus now, b=13 & a=14

in statement c=++a, value of a is incremented by 1 first and then it is assigned to c. thus c=15 & a=15.